# Где Android Studio хранит все свои настройки в Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio

Хочу почистить кеши, а может даже переустановить студию. Какие папки нужно почистить, чтобы избавиться от мусора, накопленного за время пользования?

знаю про

~/.android

~/.AndroidStudio{version}

~/.gradle/caches (чтобы облегчить индексирование)

Может есть что то ещё? Как результат хочу получить "чистую" установку, не обременённую ничем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ~/.AndroidStudio/, конфиги и система
2. ~/.android
3. ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop
4. Стандартная папка для студии - /usr/local/, или /opt/ для всех.
5. SDK обычно в ~/Android.

В дополнение глянуть: `whereis android`